# Pygsheets - non-interactive oauth authentication

Tags: google-oauth, airflow, pygsheets

I'm attempting to use Apache Airflow and pygsheets to upload to various Team Drives. When using oauth authentication, because it's an Airflow task, there's no interactive terminal for inputting the authorization code returned by Google.

I know that using a service account would typically work, but unfortunately, we're unable to give Google Drive access to users outside of our organization (so no xxxxxxx@gserviceaccount.com).

Is there any way to use oauth in a non-interactive manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can authorize the account locally and then copy the generated credentials file to the server. Then use that file for authorization, it won't ask for code again.